# Why template specialization doesn't work in gcc

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I'd like to write typelist methods to operate with microcontrollers GPIO's.

I'd like to create list of GPIO's and select only pins of specific port.
So, `GetPinWithPort` template has specialisation which checks provided type.

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
struct tlist
{
    using type = tlist;
};

template <typename T> class debug_t;

#define MAKE_PORT(NAME, ID)\
    class NAME\
    {\
        public:\
        static void Set(uint32_t v) { };\
        static void Reset(uint32_t v) { };\
        enum { id = ID };\
    };

MAKE_PORT(Porta, 'A');
MAKE_PORT(Portb, 'B');

template <class PORT, uint8_t PIN>
class TPin
{
public:
    static void Set() { PORT::Set(1 << PIN); }
    static void Reset() { PORT::Reset(1 << PIN); }

    typedef PORT port;
    enum { pin = PIN };
};

template <class TPort, class T>
struct GetPinWithPort {
    using type = tlist<>;
};

template <typename TPort, uint32_t N>
struct GetPinWithPort<TPort, TPin<TPort, N>>
{
    using type = TPin<TPort, N>;
};

int main()
{

    using pina = GetPinWithPort<Porta, TPin<Porta, 1> >::type;

    // std::cout << typeid(pina).name() << std::endl;  //Visual Studio gives: class TPin<class Porta,1>
    debug_t<pina> d; //gcc output: tlist<>

}
```

Visual Studio gives expected result. But gcc - empty list. 
What is wrong here?

Comment: You have only declared debug_t not defined it anywhere.

Comment: @Kapil That's on purpose.  It is a trick to get the compiler to give you an error that gives you the exact type given to the template.

Comment: clang also gives the results I would expect.  Not sure what is going on with GCC but changing `template <typename TPort, uint32_t N>` to `template <typename TPort, auto N>` gets it to work.  No idea why it is needed though.

Comment: It's crazy that Visual Studio gets the template right and GCC has a weird result. I originally thought that VS must be the wrong one, but if clang also works than maybe this is actually a bug with GCC.

Comment: @NathanOliver: there is probablyy a dupe with `std::array` when trying to specialise for `std::array<T, N>` with `N` of type `int` instead of `std::size_t`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
template <typename TPort, uint8_t N>  // or auto
struct GetPinWithPort<TPort, TPin<TPort, N>>
```

not

```
template <typename TPort, uint32_t N>
struct GetPinWithPort<TPort, TPin<TPort, N>>
```

because (I am **not** a language lawer, it's just how I understand i):

```
template <class PORT, uint8_t PIN>
class TPin {}
// and 
using pina = GetPinWithPort<Porta, TPin<Porta, 1> >::type;
```

In the specialisation gcc have to choose between:

```
class T
```

and

```
TPin<TPort, uint32_t>
```

and the type it have is:

```
TPin<Porta, 1>
```

So may be gcc resolve the `TPin<Porta, 1>` to `TPin<Porta, uint8_t>` then fail the specialisation.

Comment: Can you say why it should be so?  MSVS and clang both work for `uint32_t`.

Comment: I have add some explanation but i am not a language lawyer, it's more how I feel it more than C++ norm or what ever

Comment: Because unsigned int is implementation dependent and not established as a standard. GCC, if I recall correctly, chooses the smallest (storage-wise) type that it can when initializing if you don't specify fixed width at time of creation.

Answer (score 1):

In this line `using pina = GetPinWithPort<Porta, TPin<Porta, 1> >::type;`
1 has the type of int not uint32_t.  So you instantiate `GetPinWithPort<Porta, int>` (the non-specialized definition), not `GetPinWithPort<Porta, uint32_t>`.

Here is what the specialization should look like to pass the right template parameter to TPin:

```
template <typename TPort, uint8_t N>
struct GetPinWithPort<TPort, TPin<TPort, N>>
{
    using type = TPin<TPort, N>;
};
```

Here is how it should be used:

```
using pina = GetPinWithPort<Porta, TPin<Porta, static_cast<uint8_t>(1)> >::type;
```

The reason for this is that C++ is very strict about using types instide of templates: very limited conversion of types is allowed.

Comment: If you change the specialization to use an `int` it still does not work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d795435e7a29d75

Comment: @NathanOliver You are right.  I should have tried it myself first.  This works: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5e94bc8cc1657ae